# how do you include email as field in all the contribution reports in Civi CRM

Tags: reports, fields

I am new to Civi and am trying to create reports for a fundraising department. How do you add email (or other columns/fields) to the standard contribution reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not seeing an option to edit the report columns/ filters etc you might be missing a permission

Comment: I don't think that is the point. I think they are saying 'hey the email field just doesn't show in the available fields' - which I agree is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Columns tab to see what fields are available for that specific report.  If the field you want is there, then just tick the box to include it in the report.  However, if the field is not listed then code changes are needed to include it.

Some reports show overlapping sets of information so if the report you are looking at does not contain the field you need, it is worth looking at other reports to see if they can be configured to provide the results you want.

If you are using Drupal then [Views](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/#drupal-views) provides a lot of flexibility for producing alternatives to Reports.

Comment: Confirming that the email field 'is not there', whereas Address fields are. seems like an oversight when Report was built imo